# Insufficient authentication scopes while write to spreadsheet from .NET

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Trying to write to google sheets from .NET .

Got exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]

Errors [

    Message[Request had insufficient authentication scopes.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]

]
```

Analog function with read works fine. Credentials are created and google sheets API is enabled. I don't see any settings while create credentials regarding read/write. Spreadsheet is shared for everyone read/write.  How to solve this problem?

```
static void UpdateEntry()
        {
            string  spreadsheetId = "1IAD2okAWZD7anbt5L4ybgD2dxHBGmsY6IkNIWHBQkBM";
            string ApplicationName = "myapp";
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials_1.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });




            String range = "new first sheet!A1"; 
            //var range = "{sheet}!D543";
            var valueRange = new ValueRange();

            var oblist = new List<object>() { "updated" };
            valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

            var updateRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range);
            updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
            var appendReponse = updateRequest.Execute();
        }
```

Comment: I was trying with both - `static string[] Scopes = {  SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly}; ` and `static string[] Scopes = {  SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets}; ` Both generates the same error.

Comment: Why include readonly if you also include the non-readonly?

Comment: @tehhowch it was from old project, but I have tested with `static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets};` also.

Comment: And this spreadsheet is shared with the Google Account / Service Account that the code executes as? And you've verified that any previously saved credentials (from when you were using `readonly`) are not being used to instantiate your current credentials?

Comment: @i my thought is that the sheets API tag encapsulates the idea that a Google spreadsheet is being accessed, and further, it is being modified from a third party environment, as opposed to native Google UI / apps script.